# Ubuntu Hangs on Boot After Installing "gnome"

Tags: apt, gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

I tried installing the gnome desktop environment on Ubuntu 15.10 by typing

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Now when I try to boot up my computer It gets stuck on this screen:

[image]

**EDIT**

I have tried some trouble shooting of my own and used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to open the console. Once there I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome
```

It continued to remove all of gnome. After it finished I tried rebooting and the boot still hangs, but it's different now:

[image]

Comment: I still have not found a solution. I have also tried restarting the gui from the command line. I get the same error.

Comment: After purging gnome, your pc is still trying to boot in using gnome display manager. So , you must change your display manager. so try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and change your display manager to lightdm. And then see what happens next.

Comment: @kashish It worked!

Comment: @kashish, But it's a comment, so I can't reward the rep bounty...

Comment: @MaxKulik, please avoid linking such unneeded high resolution pictures, resample/resize them before uploading (>5m each that wasting of user network bandwidth who trying to help). Btw, you have enough reputation to attach pictures. (why linking to google drive)

Comment: @Sneetsher, I will work on formatting my Questions better when using images. Since my computer wasn't working I was doing this from my phone.

Comment: @kashish , would you post an answer, so you can get your deserved bounty from MaxKulik.

Comment: @kashish, What he said ^^^

Comment: @MaxKulik, :) I missed that point, nice that you got solved.

Comment: @Sneetsher, In most cases I would have already just re-installed Ubuntu but this time I wanted to to do it right haha. I really didn't want to re-start again. Plus I knew it had to just be something simple due to the fact I wan't getting any errors.

Comment: @MaxKulik, Good so you learned new things. I forget to mention you were able to change resolution/quality in the phone before taking the pictures.  ;) hopefully you will not get similar problems (where unable to login)

Comment: @MaxKulik answer written :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After purging gnome, your pc is still trying to boot in using gnome display manager. So , you must change your display manager. so try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and change your display manager to lightdm.