# Ubuntu froze after gnome install

Tags: boot, gnome, kernel, kylin

After I installed GNOME and did a normal restart then the boot process stopped in Ubuntu logo (Kylin). I have tried to go on recovery mode, memory test and several ways that are offered but no result until now. I have several kernel versions available (4.8 latest if not mistaken) and none of them works. I tried also ctrl+alt+F1 but it will go in system information, then the only option is ESC which boots Windows. I tried terminal also but don't know which commands to put there. 
I don't want to format as I was having problems with wifi and barely someone fixed it. What can I do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to log back on again by :-

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and change your display manager to lightdm.

I found information about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712233/ubuntu-hangs-on-boot-after-installing-gnome)